# How to maintain the dynamic generated textboxes after postback

Tags: html, asp.net, postback

I am generating dynamic html textboxes in my aspx page. I add a button for do some functionality. now whenever I click on my button it post back and all the dynamic generated textboxes go from my form for this I have to add it again. But I want to maintain these textboxes after postback. Here is the code how i am generating textboxes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textid = null;
    var textid1 = null;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        setupAutoComplete(textid);
        setupAutoComplete1(textid1);
        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButton").click(function () {

            if (counter > 5) {
                alert("Limit Exceeds");
                return false;
            }

            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
            textid = "textbox" + counter;
            textid1 = "textbox" + counter+1;

            //            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
            //        '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
            //        '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value=""  class="auto">');

            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div class="fields-left"><label> Leaving from</label><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" class="auto"/>  </div><div class="fields-right"> <label> Going to</label>  <input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + 1 + '" class="auto"/> </div>');
            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

            setupAutoComplete(textid);
            setupAutoComplete1(textid1);
            counter++;
        });

        $("#removeButton").click(function () {
            if (counter == 1) {
                alert("No more textbox to remove");
                return false;
            }

            counter--;

            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

        });


    });


     var setupAutoComplete= function SearchText2(textid) {
         $('.auto').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Home.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'code':'" + document.getElementById(textid).value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                                           response(data.d);

                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    var setupAutoComplete1 = function SearchText3(textid1) {
        $('.auto').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Home.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'code':'" + document.getElementById(textid1).value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);

                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

now in this code I am generating maximun 10 textboxes two in each row and after that I write some code for json autocomplete for each dynamic generated textbox. Now problem is this when i click on my button after that its postback and all the textboxes and its values goes away. I am unable to maintain these textboxes. Can anybody tell me how can we maintain the dymanic generated textboxes after postback?

Thanks

Comment: You have a better shot at it if you create the controls using a postback on the server.

Comment: can u explain it witha  example pls?? @deostroll

Comment: No offence. Helping you "this" way is not something beneficial to the community of stackoverflowers. Clearly you could have tried it on your own: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317794 Please try this out. If you run into problems, mention that in the question post, and intimate, so I can help out.